# JDBC transactions and ResultSet(s) and SELECT statements

Tags: java, select, jdbc, transactions, resultset

Because most tutorials I was able to find recently on **JDBC & transactions** usually cover only very simple cases like:

1. **Start** transaction
2. Issue **several UPDATE / INSERT** statements
3. **Commit** transaction
4. **Rollback** if any error occurs during transaction

I was wondering how does the correct *template* of JDBC transaction look like, especially in cases when there are **SELECT** statements involved.

As far as I've understood, the general template looks something like:

```
final int previousIsolationLevel = connection.getTransactionIsolation();
try {
    connection.setTransactionIsolation(desiredIsolationLevel);
    connection.setAutoCommit(false); // starting transaction

    // executing UPDATE / INSERT statements here using ps.executeUpdate(...)
    // executing SELECT statements and storing references to result sets like:
    // ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery(...);
    // ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery(...);
    // ...
    // ResultSet rsN = psN.executeQuery(...);

    connection.commit(); // committing transaction

    // reading data from rs1, ... , rsN AFTER commit like
    // while(rs1.next()) { ... }, while(rs2.next()) { ... }, ...
} catch (final Throwable ex) {
    connection.rollback(); // rolling back the transaction upon any exception
    // doing exception-handling stuff
} finally {
    connection.setAutoCommit(true); // setting auto-commit mode back to true
    connection.setTransactionIsolation(previousIsolationLevel); // setting transaction isolation to previous value
}
```

So the questions are:

1. Is above mentioned template correct at least only for **UPDATE / INSERT statements**?
2. Is it correct that if any **SELECT** statement occurs during transaction it is **wrong** to read it's **ResultSet** before commit?
3. Are there any correlation between **transaction isolation level** and possibility to read from **ResultSets** before invoke to **connection.commit()** ? *[this question extends 2nd one]*
4. Does the same rules apply to **ResultSet** returned from [PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) after **INSERT statement** was executed?

**NOTE**: I would like to find the most generic approach, but if it's very vendor specific, I'm using **MySQL** database. Though of course, I'm interested in and grateful for any help on this topic!

Comment: Why would you read the result sets after the commit? What would be the point of setting an isolation level if you don't read anything during the transaction? The isolation level precisely defines what the transaction can read. And anyway, you often ant to insert and update values that depend on what yoy have read from the database.

Comment: @JBNizet `Why would you read the result sets after the commit?` - somehow I started to think that `commit()` method applies also to `ps.executeQuery()` method and that `ResultSet` would be empty if I read it before `commit()` method :) But, your phrase `The isolation level precisely defines what the transaction can read.` clarified (and simplified) a LOT! I don't have much experience with transactions, though read some theory, looks like I've missed something. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: AFAIK most drivers default to `ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT` which should be a big hint. Just so you know,  `setAutoCommit` doesn't actually start a transaction in most drivers, it just disables auto-commit, a JDBC driver implicitly starts a transaction when one is needed (for example statement prepare or execute).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `AFAIK most drivers default to ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT which should be a big hint` - yes, that's a good hint (don't know why I started to think that `ResultSets` should be read after `commit` :)) And thanks for the remark concerning `setAutoCommit` - didn't know that.

Comment: @JBNizet would you mind if I post answer to this question myself using your info from your comment?